# SU retag request: [wireless-network] --> [wireless-networking]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Retag [wireless-network(28)](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-network) to [wireless-networking(349)](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-network).

Also, there is also the more general [wireless(222)](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless), but this one may not be an exact match on all questions.

Answer (score 2):

I've gone ahead and done this merge.  The various network-related tags on SU are still a huge ugly nightmare, but at the moment I'm not coming up with a good idea for a clean fix.

I'd like to split [wireless-networking] into [wireless] and [networking], but that will mean lots of manual retagging.  Before undertaking that, I'd like to have a clear concept of what networking tags should be in use.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question.  We also have a [**[wlan]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wlan) (20) tag, and [**[wifi]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wifi) (219).

On the wired side, we have something similar:

- [**[ethernet]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ethernet) (68)
- [**[lan]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lan) (81)
- [**[wan]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wan) (2)
- [**[network]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network) (226)
- [**[networking]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/networking) (673)
- [**[home-networking]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/home-networking) (156)

My first thought is that you've asked for a good change.  But, I like having separate tags for the *concept* ([networking]) and the *thing* ([network] or [lan] or [wan]), and I don't see any reason not to do the same thing on the wireless side.

So, at the very least this is a good opportunity to discuss, and keep our tags somewhat consistent.

- *Should* we get rid of the [network] and [wireless-network] tags and move them into [networking] and [wireless-networking]?
- Should we take care to replace them with [lan], [wan], or [wlan] where appropriate?  (Or should we simply fold those into the [*networking] tags as well?)

Thoughts?

Comment: Why not split them up and keep only the [wireless], [network] and [networking] tags? That way you can still use all the different tags which you say are on the wired side (although I think there's nothing specifically "wired" about those, except for [ethernet] maybe) in combination with the [wireless] tag.

Comment: @fretje: not a bad thought.  i'd like to know what others think as well.