# SU Retag Request: [network] --> [networking]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, networking

Similar to [SU Retag Request: wireless-network --> wireless-networking](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/912/su-retag-request-wireless-network-wireless-networking).

Can we retag [network](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network) to [networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/networking)?

Was doing this manually because I saw [this first](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/networking+network), until I saw it [lists 400+ questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network). :-(

A **synonym** might even fit better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have merged [network](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network) into [networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/networking) and created the synonym.