# SU Retag Request: [internet] <-> [networking] <-> [connection]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, networking

We might want to consider migrating between the similar and perhaps duplicate tags:

- [web](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/web)
- [internet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet)
- [networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/networking) (I [proposed](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1916/su-retag-request-network-networking) [network](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network) -> [networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/networking) here)
- [connection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/connection)

All questions of [internet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet) could be placed in one of those:

- [web](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/web)
- [networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/networking)

All questions of [connection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/connection) might fit in [networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/networking).

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with the [web](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/web) and [internet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet) merge since internet doesn't neccessary mean it is a [web](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/web) related problem, it could be a problem with other [internet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet) protocols. [web](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/web) specifically indicates that it is a web related issue, ie. browsing or web page related.

I also disagree with [connection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/connection) since it could indicate a connection with a device via USB or Firewire.

I have however merged [network](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network) into [networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/networking) and created the synonym for it.

Comment: Your explanation for having a separate tag [web] and [connection] does make sense, thank you...